# Unable to locate package pthread

Tags: apt, software-installation

I'm using Ubuntu 14. I'm trying to install GNU Radio and, when I try to configure, `pthread` library is missing. I then do:

```
sudo apt-get install pthread
```

I get this as return:

```
akula@akula:~/OpenBts/gnuradio-3.4.0$ cd ~
akula@akula:~$ sudo apt-get install pthread
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pthread
```

I already did all kinds of updates and everything else I found on the internet.

If anyone could help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: What is the exact error message (that prompts you to install libpthread)?

Comment: Why do you want to install pthread? Its a C library available by default.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The correct name of the package is **`libpthread-stubs0-dev`**:

```
sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

Comment: It's already installed in 15.10 at least.

Comment: Sorry I m late to the party... But I've always been wondering: how the hell do you know/find out the name of that package? There is no way you just guess such a name!

Comment: You still kind of have to know the package name, but `apt search pthread` is helpful for listing packages that mention pthread.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev` seems to do nothing.

`gcc -lpthread` will still result in a missing pthreads error.

Use instead:
`gcc -pthread` and get a missing main function error.  This is expected behavior if everything else is okay.

This flag works on example pthread C file programs.

In Mint (thus Ubuntu)
The file `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so` is in the libc6:amd64 package.