# Install PHP Pthread in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, 13.04, php

I want to install `PThread` in ubuntu with following command

```
sudo apt-get install pthread

ubuntu@ip-172-32-25-110:/var$ sudo apt-get install pthread
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pthread
```

But it display message like `E: Unable to locate package pthread`.

I also tried following command

```
sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpthread-stubs0-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 139 not upgraded.
```

So my question is how to install PThread in ubuntu ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to locate package pthread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453860/unable-to-locate-package-pthread)

Comment: @markkirby This question is duplicated but I do not get solution

Comment: Please be more precise about what exactly you are trying to install.

Comment: @fkraiem I want to install `PThread` PHP Package.

Comment: @markkirby You do not understand my question. My question is how to install pthread not PHP?

Comment: OK Forget the answer, I don't know enough about your system to write a good one, here is my source for the install http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php Answers 3+ are for linux based OS.

Answer (score 1):

Installing this package seems to be problematic on Ubuntu, because the version of PHP shipped in the official Ubuntu repositories is not compiled with the necessary options. Namely, tring to install it with `pecl install pthreads-1.0.0` results in

```
checking checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

The most straightforward way to fix this seems to be to use PHP packages with ZTS support enabled, which can be found in some PPAs (such as [this one](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5)). Then, installing the PHP Pthreads extension through PECL should work (I have not tested this).